# Long click listener on 2 buttons at the same time

Tags: java, android

I would like to do a long click listener for 2 buttons . I mean clicking on the 2 buttons(a and b) at the same time will close the app. 
How can i manage this? thank you in advance .

Comment: Check this out : http://www.passsy.de/activity_with_multitouch_for_buttons/

Comment: You can use flag to check if two buttons are clicked or not

Comment: @twenk11k it was working correctly . But i want a long click on it.

Comment: @Reena in this case the methods will be mixed . Or they will be duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this solution using isPressed method. It is working.

```
    iconD.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
             if (view.getId() == R.id.picture_d) {
                 if (iconR.isPressed() && iconD.isPressed()) {
                       askingForClosingTheApp();
                 }
              }
              return true;
         }
   });
```